# What is this OOTB Empty Web part?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience

I can see the below Empty web part available in the Modern Pages. Can anyone provide any details on what is this or any documentation about the same?
[image]

Comment: Looks like someone in Microsoft playing with creating ACEs & created this "BotDrivenAdaptiveCardExtension web part (Empty WebPart)". 